# JSF ManagedBean size limit

Tags: java, jsf

I have a managed bean like this:

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class bean implements Serializable {
    private List<Project> projectList = new ArrayList<Project>();
    @PostConstruct
    private void init() {
       projectList = projectManager.getActiveProjects();
    }
    public void save() {
        //save
    }
}
```

The problem is when I call the save method from the xhtml page.
I expected to simply enter into the save method and do the task. Unfortunately it only enters into the init method and never enters in save.

It seems the problem is from the projectList list. If I don't save the projects in a list then everything works fine.

Also I have this configuration in web.xml

```
<param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
<param-value>client</param-value>
```

If I set the value to server it will work, but I don't know if I can do it.
So my question(s) are:a jsf managedbean has a maximum size? If yes then what can I do if I need to store a "bigger" array list? Setting the STATE_SAVING_METHOD to server is a good solution?

Comment: _It seems the problem is from the projectList list. If I don't save the projects in a list then everything works fine._ But why do you think the **length** is the culprit. Please create a [mcve] to demonstrate the problem (see also http://www.stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info). Your question might  be an http://xyproblem.info and It might even be that in the course of creating a [mcve], you find the real cause.

Answer (score 0):

STATE_SAVING_METHOD is to specify where is component status saved. 
When you use 'server' the JSF container maintains the component status in the server memory, and client will be not asked for the component status.
When you use 'client' the JSF container asume that the client will be store the component status, no server memory is needed but client will need send the component status every time, so the band width will be increased.

In your case, the problem can be a conversion error (you are sending a 'Project' list).

To discover errors that may be hidden for messages, use development mode:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
    <param-value>Development</param-value>
</context-param>
```